# Average across rows, but leaving out own group

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to calculate an average across groups, but leaving the observation's own group.

My data looks like this:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- tribble(
  ~year, ~country, ~value,
  2001, "France", 150, 
  2002, "France", 53, 
  2003, "France", 31, 
  2004, "France", 10, 
  2005, "France", 30, 
  2006, "France", 37, 
  2007, "France", 54, 
  2008, "France", 58, 
  2009, "France", 50, 
  2010, "France", 40, 
  2011, "France", 49, 
  2001, "USA", 55,
  2002, "USA", 53,
  2003, "USA", 64,
  2004, "USA", 70,
  2005, "USA", 80,
  2006, "USA", 160,
  2007, "USA", 55,
  2008, "USA", 53,
  2009, "USA", 71,
  2010, "USA", 11,
  2011, "USA", 10,
  2001, "GBR", 12,
  2002, "GBR", 8,
  2003, "GBR", 7,
  2004, "GBR", -5,
  2005, "GBR", NA,
  2006, "GBR", NA,
  2007, "GBR", NA,
  2008, "GBR", 5,
  2009, "GBR", 12,
  2010, "GBR", 16,
  2011, "GBR", 25
)
```

I have a balanced panel dataset, so the years are the same for all countries.

I would like to define a new column that takes the mean across the values from the other two countries.

So the value for `2001, "France"` would be 33.5, the mean of 55 (from `2001, "USA"`) and 12 (from `2001, "GBR"`). My messy real-life dataset is much bigger, so doing this by hand would not be a good idea.